# Calling user defined exception but instead when others than exception is raising

Tags: oracle, exception

I have a anonymous block like below

```
DECLARE
exc1 EXCEPTION;
i integer:='1';
BEGIN
 BEGIN
    IF i = 1 THEN
        RAISE exc1;
    END IF;

 EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        raise_application_error(-20481,
                    'Error while inserting/update into Table- ' ||
                    SQLERRM);
 END;
EXCEPTION
WHEN exc1 THEN
    raise_application_error(-20001, 'test123');

END;
```

I just want to raise the exc1 exception. But here instead **when others then** exception is raising. I specifically raise the exception exc1 in if condition block so it has to call right?

Comment: The reason your `OTHERS` exception handler is being executed is because the exc1 handler is not in scope. when your `if` block executes its true code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option here is to have just one exception block:

```sql
DECLARE
exc1 EXCEPTION;
i integer:='1';
BEGIN
    IF i = 1 THEN
        RAISE exc1;
    END IF;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN exc1 THEN
        raise_application_error(-20001, 'test123');

    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        raise_application_error(-20481,
                    'Error while inserting/update into Table- ' ||
                    SQLERRM);
END;
/
```

But if you *really* need nested anonymous block with own exceptions blocks, you need to add one more exception handler:

```sql
DECLARE
exc1 EXCEPTION;
i integer:='1';
BEGIN
     BEGIN
        IF i = 1 THEN
            RAISE exc1;
        END IF;

     EXCEPTION
        WHEN exc1 THEN
            raise;
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            raise_application_error(-20481,
                        'Error while inserting/update into Table- ' ||
                        SQLERRM);
     END;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN exc1 THEN
        raise_application_error(-20001, 'test123');
END;
/
```

PS. I'd suggest you do not use `when others then` without adding original exception into the error stack, ie 3rd parameter of raise_application_error() should be `true`:

```sql
DECLARE
exc1 EXCEPTION;
i integer:='1';
BEGIN
    IF i = 1 THEN
        RAISE exc1;
    END IF;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN exc1 THEN
        raise_application_error(-20001, 'test123', true);

    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        raise_application_error(-20481,
                    'Error while inserting/update into Table- ' ||
                    SQLERRM
                    , true);
END;
/
```